# I have a problem with break of the programm

Tags: python-3.x

I have a problem with the fact that when I write "n "at the time of starting the" #Restart "part and should ideally write" Goodbye " and close after 10 seconds, but it starts the else process: which is at the very end, and restarts everything. but I enter everything correctly and the error I called " Input Error!"it shouldn't be, just help who can, I don't know why this is happening .-.

------------------------------------------------------------------start------------------------------------------------------------

1-Russian, 2-English, 3-UA? (Without spaces):2

The discriminant is derived from the root?(y/n):y

Enter a number a:1

Enter a number b:2

Enter a number c:3

Discriminant = -8.0

No roots!

If there are many numbers after the point then the answer is either a fraction or the answer is not correct.

Do you want to continue?(y/n):n

Goodbye!

Input Error!

Restarting...

1-Russian, 2-English, 3-UA? (Without spaces):

----------------------------------------------------------------end------------------------------------------------------------

Start of code:

```
While True:   
    #Language

    language = input("1-Russian, 2-English, 3-UA? (Without spaces):")

    #English

    if language == "2":

        while True:

            #Output from the root
            kor = input( "The discriminant is derived from the root?(y/n):")

            #a,b,c
            try:
                a = float( input( "Enter a number a:"))
                b = float( input("Enter a number b:"))
                c = float( input( "Enter a number c:"))
            except (ValueError): 
                import time
                print ("Input error! This is not a number") 
                print ("Restarting...") 
                time.sleep(1) 
                continue

            #Finding D   

            D = (b * b) - 4 * a * c 

            #Finding x1, x2 and print this

            if kor == "y":

                if D > 0:
                    import math
                    xone = (-b + (math.sqrt(D))) / (2 * a)     
                    xtwo = (-b - (math.sqrt(D))) / (2 * a) 
                    print ( "Discriminant = " + str(D))
                    print ( "x1 = " + str(xone))
                    print ( "x2 = " + str(xtwo))
                    print ( "If there are many numbers after the point then the answer is either a fraction or the answer is not correct.")

                if D == 0:
                    import math
                    x = -b / (2 * a)
                    print ( "Disctiminant = " + str(D))
                    print ( "x = " + str(x))
                    print ( "If there are many numbers after the point then the answer is either a fraction or the answer is not correct.")
                if D < 0:
                    import math
                    print ( "Discriminant = " + str(D))
                    print ( "No roots! " )
                    print ( "If there are many numbers after the point then the answer is either a fraction or the answer is not correct.")

                #Restart

                restart = input("Do you want to continue?(y/n):")

                if restart == "y":
                    import time
                    print( "Restarting...")
                    time.sleep(1)
                    continue

                if restart == "n":
                    import time
                    print( "Goodbye!")
                    time.sleep(10)
                    break
                else:
                    import time
                    print( "Input Error!")
                    print( "Restarting...")
                    time.sleep(1)
                    continue


             if kor == "n":

                if D > 0:
                    import math
                    xone = (-b + D) / (2 * a)     
                    xtwo = (-b - D) / (2 * a) 
                    print ( "Discriminant = " + str(D))
                    print ( "x1 = " + str(xone))
                    print ( "x2 = " + str(xtwo))
                    print ( "if there are many numbers after the point then the answer is either a fraction or the answer is not correct.")
                    print ( "Try selecting a discriminant that is derived from the root!")

                if D == 0:
                    import math
                    x = -b / (2 * a)
                    print ( "Discriminant = " + str(D))
                    print ( "x = " + str(x))
                    print ( "if there are many numbers after the point then the answer is either a fraction or the answer is not correct.")
                if D < 0:
                    import math
                    print ( "Discriminant = " + str(D))
                    print ( "no roots! " )
                    print ( "if there are many numbers after the point then the answer is either a fraction or the answer is not correct.")


                #Restart
                restart = input("Do you want to continue?(y/n):")

                if restart == "y":
                    import time
                    print( "Restarting...")
                    time.sleep(1)
                    continue

                if restart == "n":
                    import time
                    print( "Goodbye!")
                    time.sleep(10)
                    break

                else:
                    import time
                    print( "Input Error!")
                    print( "Restarting...")
                    time.sleep(1)
                    continue

            else:
                import time
                print( "Input Error!")
                print( "Restarting...")
                time.sleep(1)
                continue

    else:
        (it`s language part)
        import time
        print( "Input Error!")
        print( "Restarting...")
        time.sleep(1)
        continue
```

Comment: `break` only breaks out of one loop, so it exits the inner while loop but then you're back to the outer loop.

Comment: do you know how to fix this? before I tried to fix the error with ValueError (when entering letters where numbers were expected, everything was closed) everything was fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code has a lot of repetition. Handling all the possible combinations of user input cases will be a lot easier if you avoid the double while loop, and use a function instead. Here is my go at restructuring it.

```
import time, math

def f():
    kor = input( "The discriminant is derived from the root?(y/n):")
    if kor not in {'y', 'n'}:
        print( "Input Error!")
        print( "Restarting...")
        time.sleep(1)
        return f()

    #a,b,c
    try:
        a = float( input( "Enter a number a:"))
        b = float( input("Enter a number b:"))
        c = float( input( "Enter a number c:"))
    except (ValueError): 
        print ("Input error! This is not a number") 
        print ("Restarting...") 
        time.sleep(1) 
        return f()

    D = (b * b) - 4 * a * c
    return kor, a, b, c, D


while True:
    language = input("1-Russian, 2-English, 3-UA? (Without spaces):")
    if language == "2":
        break

while language == "2":
    kor, a, b, d, D = f()

    if D > 0:
        if kor == "y":
            xone = (-b + (math.sqrt(D))) / (2 * a)     
            xtwo = (-b - (math.sqrt(D))) / (2 * a)
        elif kor == "n":
            print ( "Discriminant = " + str(D))
            print ( "x1 = " + str(xone))
            print ( "x2 = " + str(xtwo))
            print ( "If there are many numbers after the point then the answer is either a fraction or the answer is not correct.")

    elif D == 0:
        x = -b / (2 * a)
        print ( "Disctiminant = " + str(D))
        print ( "x = " + str(x))
        print ( "If there are many numbers after the point then the answer is either a fraction or the answer is not correct.")

    elif D < 0:
        print ( "Discriminant = " + str(D))
        print ( "No roots! " )
        print ( "If there are many numbers after the point then the answer is either a fraction or the answer is not correct.")

    restart = input("Do you want to continue?(y/n):")

    if restart == "y":
        print( "Restarting...")
        time.sleep(1)

    elif restart == "n":
        print( "Goodbye!")
        time.sleep(10)
        break
    else:
        print( "Input Error!")
        print( "Restarting...")
        time.sleep(1)
```